# Facebook like counter has been zeroed

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-like

In some stage few days ago many of the website pages' counter has been zeroed.

After various examinations, using facebook's debug tool (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) I realized that there is no problem in my plugin embedded code. The counter in the debug took shows the exact number as it shows in the website.

But still, what can we do?? is there a way to restore the lost likes counts (and users lists that liked the pages etc.)?
Maybe something else has happened?
Many thanks,
Ehud

Comment: Check whether url are same as previous. If url generated dynamically and if it changes, then it will happen.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, But site urls hasn't changed. Or do you mean urls for the plugin? I see two hidden input tags with urls, inside the iframe plugin form. one with href and the second with iframe_referer. both has unchanged page url as value.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated. I'm really helpless here. Didn't find any help in facebook forums and in other places..